# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando remover um item de uma tabela, porém ele me retorna esse erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'endGoal' of undefined
>       at $$childScopeClass.$scope.removeGoal

segue a parte do angular onde acontece o erro:

```
$scope.removeGoal = function (goal) {
 var index = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.indexOf(goal);
 if ($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length-1 > 0) {
    if ($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index].endGoal == null) {
     $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index - 1].endGoal = null;
    }
    else
    {
     $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index - 1].endGoal = 
     $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index].endGoal; 
    }
  }
  $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Codigo Inteiro

```
/// <reference path="../../_references.js" />
/// <reference path="../registrationModel.js" />
(function () {
    angular.module("registrationModule").controller("IndicatorFormController",
        ['$scope', '$filter', 'dateService', 'indicatorRepository', 'selectionContentService', '$compile', 'indicatorGoalRepository',
            function ($scope, $filter, dateService, indicatorRepository, selectionContentService, $compile, indicatorGoalRepository) {

                $scope.frequencies = [
                    { id: 1, name: 'Diário' },
                    { id: 2, name: 'Semanal' },
                    { id: 3, name: 'Mensal' },
                    { id: 4, name: 'Anual' },
                ];


                //Process
                $scope.selectedProcesses = [];
                $scope.processesToAdd = [];
                $scope.processesToRemove = [];


                //Branches
                $scope.branchesToAdd = [];
                $scope.branchesToRemove = [];
                $scope.selectedBranches = [];

                //Users
                $scope.usersToAdd = [];
                $scope.usersToRemove = [];
                $scope.selectedUsers = [];

                $scope.indicator = {
                    active: true,
                    iso: true,
                    indicatorGoals: []
                };

                //Inicializa o indicar com o mes e ano iniciais
                if (typeof (Indicator) != 'undefined' && Indicator != null) {

                    $scope.indicator = Indicator;
                    $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.sort(function (a, b) {
                        var keyA = new Date(a.startGoal),
                            keyB = new Date(b.startGoal);
                        // Compare the 2 dates
                        if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
                        if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
                        return 0;
                    });
                    $scope.branchesToAdd = $scope.indicator.branches;
                    $scope.indicator.branches = [];
                    $scope.processesToAdd = $scope.indicator.processes;
                    $scope.indicator.processes = [];
                    $scope.usersToAdd = $scope.indicator.responsibleUsers;
                    $scope.indicator.responsibleUsers = [];
                    console.log($scope.usersToAdd)

                    console.log($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals)
                    if ($scope.indicator.endCollect != null) {
                        var old_value = angular.copy($scope.indicator.endCollect.replace("-", "").replace("-", "").substring(0, 8));
                        var day = old_value.substring(6, 8) + "/";
                        var mes = old_value.substring(4, 6) + "/";
                        var year = old_value.substring(0, 4);
                        old_value = day + mes + year;
                    }

                }

                //Pega os itenvalos [trimestral, semestral] ...
                $scope.intervals = dateService.intervals;
                $scope.intervals.push({ id: 5, name: "Meses Consecutivos" });


                if ($scope.indicator.name != null) {
                    if ($scope.indicator.endCollect == null)
                        $("#div-endless").hide();
                }

                $("input#active").live("click", function () {

                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("#endless").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("input#inp_endless").val("");
                        $("#div-endless").hide();
                    } else {
                        $("#endless").prop("disabled", false);
                        $("input#inp_endless").val(old_value);
                        $("#div-endless").show();
                    }
                });


                $scope.addProcesses = function () {

                    var modal = $(this).getModalWindow();

                    //Get Process Selection
                    selectionContentService.getProcessSelectionContent().then(function (content) {
                        $.modal({
                            content: content,
                            title: 'Preencha o formulário',
                            maxHeight: 480,
                            width: 660,
                            buttons: {
                                "Selecionar": function (wind) {
                                    $("#selectableProcessList input:checked").each(function () {
                                        //var partes = $(this).val().split(";");
                                        //var id = parseInt(partes[0], 10);
                                        //var name = partes[1];
                                        var id = parseInt($(this).val());
                                        var name = $(this).data('text');

                                        $scope.processesToAdd.push({ processID: id, name: name });
                                        $scope.$apply();
                                    });

                                    modal.show();
                                    wind.closeModal();
                                },
                                "Cancelar_red": function (wind) { modal.show(); wind.closeModal(); }
                            },
                            onClose: function () {
                                modal.show();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                };

                $scope.removeProcesses = function () {
                    angular.forEach($scope.selectedProcesses, function (v) {
                        var index = $scope.processesToAdd.indexOf(v);
                        $scope.processesToRemove.push(v);
                        $scope.processesToAdd.splice(index, 1);
                    });
                };




                $scope.addBranches = function () {
                    var modal = $(this).getModalWindow();

                    //Get Branch Selection
                    //true para pegar com multipleselects [checkboxes] false para [radio]
                    selectionContentService.getBranchSelectionContent(true, false).then(function (content) {
                        $.modal({
                            content: content,
                            title: 'Selecione as unidades',
                            maxHeight: 480,
                            width: 660,
                            buttons: {
                                "Selecionar": function (wind) {
                                    $("#selectableBranchList input:checked").each(function () {
                                        var partes = $(this).val().split(";");
                                        var id = parseInt(partes[0], 10);
                                        var name = partes[1];
                                        $scope.branchesToAdd.push({ branchID: id, name: name });
                                        $scope.$apply()
                                    });

                                    modal.show();
                                    wind.closeModal();
                                },
                                "Cancelar_red": function (wind) { modal.show(); wind.closeModal(); }
                            },
                            onClose: function () {
                                modal.show();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                };


                $scope.removeBranches = function () {
                    angular.forEach($scope.selectedBranches, function (v) {
                        var index = $scope.branchesToAdd.indexOf(v);
                        $scope.branchesToRemove.push(v);
                        $scope.branchesToAdd.splice(index, 1);
                    });
                };


                $scope.addUsers = function () {

                    var modal = $(this).getModalWindow();

                    //Get User Selection
                    //true para pegar com multipleselects [checkboxes] false para [radio]
                    selectionContentService.getUserSelectionContent(true).then(function (content) {
                        $.modal({
                            content: content,
                            title: 'Selecio os usuários',
                            maxHeight: 480,
                            width: 660,
                            buttons: {
                                "Selecionar": function (wind) {
                                    $("#selectableUserList input:checked").each(function () {
                                        var id = parseInt($(this).val());
                                        var name = $(this).data('text');
                                        $scope.usersToAdd.push({ personID: id, name: name });
                                        $scope.$apply();
                                    });

                                    modal.show();
                                    wind.closeModal();
                                },
                                "Cancelar_red": function (wind) { modal.show(); wind.closeModal(); }
                            },
                            onClose: function () {
                                modal.show();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                };


                $scope.removeUsers = function () {
                    angular.forEach($scope.selectedUsers, function (v) {
                        var index = $scope.usersToAdd.indexOf(v);
                        $scope.usersToRemove.push(v);
                        $scope.usersToAdd.splice(index, 1);
                    });
                };


                $scope.addGoal = function () {
                    selectionContentService.getIndicatorGoalForm().then(function (content) {

                        var modal = $(this).getModalWindow();

                        $.modal({
                            title: 'Cadastro de Metas',
                            content: content,
                            width: 600,
                            maxHeight: 480,
                            onOpen: function () {
                                $compile($(this))($scope);
                            },
                            buttons: {
                                'Salvar': function (wind) {
                                    clearErrorsMessages();

                                    var scopeChild = $scope.$$childTail;
                                    var indicatorGoal = scopeChild.indicatorGoal;
                                    var oldGoal = scopeChild.indicatorGoal;

                                    scopeChild.indicatorGoalErrors = [];

                                    indicatorGoalRepository.save(oldGoal, indicatorGoal).then(
                                        function (res) {

                                            oldGoal = angular.copy($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[$scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length-1]);

                                            //if ($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length > 1) {
                                            //    //$scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[$scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length - 2].endGoal =
                                            //    //   $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[$scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length - 1].startGoal;
                                            //}                              
                                            if ($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length >= 1) {
                                                //oldGoal.endGoal = indicatorGoal.startGoal;

                                                //Arrumo o formato da data
                                                var correctDate = indicatorGoal.startGoal.replace("-", " ").replace("-", " ").substring(0, 10);
                                                var newData = new Date(correctDate);
                                                //Tira um dia da data
                                                newData = newData.setDate(newData.getDate() - 1);
                                                //recebe a data
                                                oldGoal.endGoal = newData;
                                                //limpa o scope anterior
                                                $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.splice(($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length - 1), 1);
                                                //Adicionar o scope anterior editado um o novo
                                                $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.push(oldGoal, indicatorGoal);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.push(indicatorGoal);
                                            }
                                            //$scope.save(false, $scope.indicator);


                                            modal.show();
                                            wind.closeModal();
                                        },
                                        function (errors) {
                                            scopeChild.indicatorGoalErrors = errors;
                                            scopeChild.validationFields();
                                        }
                                    );

                                    //var indicatorGoalForm = $scope.$$childTail.indicatorGoalForm;
                                    //$scope.$$childTail.saveGoal();
                                    //if (indicatorGoalForm.$valid) {
                                    //    var lastGoal = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length > 0 ? $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[$scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length - 1] : null;
                                    //    if (lastGoal != null) {
                                    //        var aux = angular.copy(lastGoal);
                                    //        var startDate = angular.copy($scope.$$childTail.indicatorGoal.startGoal);
                                    //        startDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1));
                                    //        aux.endGoal = angular.copy(startDate);
                                    //        $scope.removeAndAdd(lastGoal, aux);
                                    //    }

                                    //    var newIndicatorGoal = angular.copy($scope.$$childTail.indicatorGoal);

                                    //    $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.push(newIndicatorGoal);

                                    //    $scope.$digest();

                                    //var newIndicatorGoal = $scope.$$childTail.indicatorGoal;

                                    //$scope.$apply(function () {
                                    //    $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.push(newIndicatorGoal);
                                    //});

                                    //modal.show();
                                    //wind.closeModal();
                                },
                                'Cancelar_red': function (wind) {
                                    $scope.$$childHead = null;

                                    modal.show();
                                    wind.closeModal();
                                }
                            },
                            onClose: function () {
                                $scope.$$childHead = null;
                            }
                        });

                    });
                };


                $scope.isLastGoal = true;

                $scope.editGoal = function (goal) {
                    var modal = $(this).getModalWindow();

                    scopeChild = $scope.$$childTail;
                    indicatorGoal = scopeChild.indicatorGoal;
                    lastGoal = scopeChild.indicatorGoal;

                    scopeChild.indicatorGoalErrors = [];

                    //Pega o index do scope
                    var index = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.indexOf(goal);

                    $scope.indicatorGoal = angular.copy($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index]);
                    //$scope.indicatorGoal = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index];

                    var scopeChild = $scope.$$childTail;
                    $scope.indicatorGoal = scopeChild.indicatorGoal;

                    var lastGoal = angular.copy($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index-1]);
                    //var lastGoal = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index-1];

                    //$scope.isLastGoal = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.indexOf(goal) == ($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length - 1);

                    selectionContentService.getIndicatorGoalForm().then(function (content) {
                        $.modal({
                            title: 'Cadastro de Metas',
                            content: content,
                            width: 600,
                            maxHeight: 480,
                            onOpen: function () {
                                $compile($(this))($scope);
                            },
                            buttons: {
                                'Salvar': function (wind) {
                                    var correctDate = $scope.indicatorGoal.startGoal.replace("-", " ").replace("-", " ").substring(0, 10);
                                    var newData = new Date(correctDate);
                                    if (index > 0) {
                                        //Tira um dia da data
                                        newData = newData.setDate(newData.getDate() - 1);
                                        //recebe a data
                                        lastGoal.endGoal = newData;

                                        $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.splice((index - 1), 1, lastGoal);
                                    }
                                    $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.splice((index),1,$scope.indicatorGoal);                               
                                    $scope.$apply();
                                    modal.show();
                                    wind.closeModal();
                                },
                                'Cancelar_red': function (wind) {
                                    $scope.$$childHead = null;
                                    $scope.indicatorGoal = null;
                                    wind.closeModal();
                                }
                            },
                            onClose: function () {
                                $scope.indicatorGoal = null;
                                $scope.$$childHead = null;
                            }
                        });

                    });
                };

                $scope.removeGoal = function (goal) {
                    var index = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.indexOf(goal);
                    if ($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length-1 > 0) {
                        if ($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index].endGoal == null) {
                            $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index - 1].endGoal = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index - 1].endGoal = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals[index].endGoal; 
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.splice(index, 1);
                };


                $scope.removeAndAdd = function (goal, adds) {
                    var index = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.indexOf(goal);
                    $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.splice(index, 1, adds);
                };


                $scope.cancel = function () {

                };

                var validationFields = function () {

                    var scopeForm = $scope.indicatorForm;
                    var form = indicatorForm;

                    if (scopeForm.name.$invalid) {
                        angular.element(form.name).addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.name), angular.element(form.name).parent());

                    if ($scope.indicator.measureUnitID == 0) {
                        angular.element(form.measureUnit).addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.measureUnit), angular.element(form.measureUnit).parent());

                    if ($scope.processesToAdd.length == 0) {
                        angular.element(form.processes).addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.processes), angular.element(form.processes).parent());

                    if ($scope.branchesToAdd.length == 0) {
                        angular.element(form.branches).addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.branches), angular.element(form.branches).parent());

                    if ($scope.usersToAdd.length == 0) {
                        angular.element(form.users).addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.users), angular.element(form.users).parent());

                    if (scopeForm.intervalAnalysis.$invalid) {
                        angular.element(form.intervalAnalysis).addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.intervalAnalysis), angular.element(form.intervalAnalysis).parent());

                    if (scopeForm.consecutiveMonths.$invalid) {
                        angular.element(form.consecutiveMonths).addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.consecutiveMonths), angular.element(form.consecutiveMonths).parent());

                    if (scopeForm.frequency.$invalid) {
                        angular.element(form.frequency).addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.frequency), angular.element(form.frequency).parent());

                    if (scopeForm.startCollect.$invalid) {
                        angular.element(form.startCollect).parent().addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }


                    if (scopeForm.endCollect.$invalid) {
                        angular.element(form.endCollect).parent().addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                    }


                    if ($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.length == 0) {
                        angular.element($("#goals")).addClass(validationClassErrosType.genericTable);
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.indicatorErros.length; i++) {
                        if ($scope.indicatorErros[i] == "A data inicial do indicador é maior que as datas das metas.") {
                            angular.element(form.startCollect).parent().addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                            angular.element($("#goals")).addClass(validationClassErrosType.genericTable);
                        }
                        if ($scope.indicatorErros[i] =="A data de início de uma nova meta é depois da data final do indicador.") {
                            angular.element(form.endCollect).parent().addClass(validationClassErrosType.input);
                        }
                    }
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.endCollect).parent(), angular.element(form.endCollect).parent());
                    validationCheckImage(angular.element(form.startCollect).parent(), angular.element(form.startCollect).parent());
                    validationCheckImage($("#goals"), $("#goals"), validationClassErrosType.genericTable);
                };

                $scope.indicatorErros = [];

                //Save
                $scope.save = function (indicator) {
                    clearErrorsMessages();
                    $scope.indicatorErros = [];

                    var objectToSave = angular.extend({},
                        indicator,
                        { usersToAdd: joinByProperty($scope.usersToAdd, 'personID', ',') },
                        { processesToAdd: joinByProperty($scope.processesToAdd, 'processID', ',') },
                        { branchesToAdd: joinByProperty($scope.branchesToAdd, 'branchID', ',') });


                    indicatorRepository.save(objectToSave)
                        .then(function () {
                            location.href = "/Indicator/Indicators";
                        }, function (errors) {
                            $scope.indicatorErros = errors;
                            validationFields();
                        })
                };

            }]);
}());
```

console.log($scope.indicator.indicatorGoals);

> (2) [{…}, {…}] 0 : {goalType: 1, above: 32, startGoal:
>   "2017-10-21T00:00:00", endGoal: 1508378400000, $$hashKey: "00E"} 1 :
>   {goalType: 1, above: 32, startGoal: "2017-10-20T00:00:00", endGoal:
>   null, $$hashKey: "00K"} length : 2
>   **proto** : Array(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indice correto

```
var teste = [{
  teste : 'oi',
  nome : 'teste'
}];

console.log(teste[0].teste);
```

> Retorno: oi

indice indefinido

```
var teste = [{
  teste : 'oi',
  nome : 'kk'
}];

console.log(teste[null].teste);
```

> mensagem [TypeError: Cannot read property 'teste' of undefined]

logo em `var index = $scope.indicator.indicatorGoals.indexOf(goal)`;

`index` está recebendo um valor nulo, basta arrumar esse trecho, porém não sei qual sua intenção com ele, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: eu noite isso eu fiz uma verificação pra vê se o index == 0 e deu certo porém estou com um outro problema agora

Comment: Meu tempo é bem relativo então não poderei te ajudar no chat, Pode ficar a vontade em abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: Está beleza vou testa algumas opções aqui antes, obrigado